# How do I prove that any bounded sequence in $R$ converges, given that ε>0?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am currently taking a course in real analysis and came across a Corollary that wasn't properly explained. How do I prove that any bounded sequence in $R$ converges?

Initially I attempted to use that show that a supremum of some sequence existed such that $sup(_n)$$(a_n)$ = a, however I found myself being incapable of finding some way to show  that it is bounded. I am not sure if I should assume it is monotone increasing or not but appreciate any help given as I am doing this individually.

Comment: That statement is false.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos where is it false? I am relatively new to studying mathematics and would appreciate some clarification

Comment: the sequence $(\sin(n))_{n\ge0}$ is bounded but doesn't converge

Comment: It is false because, for instance, the sequence $1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$ is bounded but it diverges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: maybe in your example $\epsilon \leq 0$ :)

Comment: Welcome to (posting at) MSE! <> There are (at least) two similar-sounding theorems: (i) A bounded _monotone_ real sequence converges; (ii) A bounded real sequence _has a convergent subsequence_. Is it possible you mean one of those, or that otherwise a hypothesis has gotten lost?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , I spoke to the prof. that gave me the Corollary and he didn't write down that the sequence was bounded and monotone. Theorem (i) is the correct question and I have since managed to prove the initial Corollary. Thank you very much for the welcoming message and I look forward to contributing more to MSE!